# How can I return a list of data from my json file to my controller file in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a json file that has a list of artists names and I need to return those list of names in my controller. How can I access those list of names in my controller? I am extremely new to working with asp.net mvc. This is what I have tried but I'm not sure if I'm going in the wrong direction.

```
[HttpGet("/artist")]
public JsonResult ArtistNames()
{
    List<Artist> showNames = _____
        .Where(name => name.ArtistName)
        .ToList();
        
    return Json();
}
```

I left the blank right there cause I'm not sure what I would put right there or even if that's the right direction. Can someone help me out?

Here is my artist model:

```
public class Artist
{
    public string ArtistName;
    public string RealName;
    public int Age;
    public string Hometown;
    public int GroupId;
    public Group Group;
}
```

this is not a real application or anything it's just an assignment to practice with. Here is the Json

```json
[
  {"ArtistName":"RZA","RealName":"Robert Diggs","Age":47,"Hometown":"New York City","GroupId":1}, 
  {"ArtistName":"Lloyd Banks","RealName":"Christopher Lloyd","Age":34,"Hometown":"New York City","GroupId":2}, 
  {"ArtistName":"The Game","RealName":"Jayceon Taylor","Age":37,"Hometown":"Compton","GroupId":2},
  {"ArtistName":"Phife Dawg","RealName":"Malik Taylor","Age":45,"Hometown":"New York City","GroupId":3}, 
  {"ArtistName":"Busta Rhymes","RealName":"Trevor Smith","Age":44,"Hometown":"New York City","GroupId":0}, 
  {"ArtistName":"Dr Dre","RealName":"Andre Young","Age":51,"Hometown":"Compton","GroupId":4}
]
```

Comment: Are you reading that JSON file into memory in the first place?

Comment: Do you literally have an actual json file sitting somewhere and you want to send it? Typically most applications read data out of a database.

Comment: Where is the information about the artists that you want to read?

Comment: i added the json file that I have. this is just a assignment(I am a student) that I am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the this code :

```
[HttpGet("/artist")]
public JsonResult ArtistNames(string artistName)
{
    var result = new List<Artist>();
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("json file path!"))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Artist>>(json);
    }

    result = result
        .Where(name => name.ArtistName)
        .ToList();
        
    return result;
}
```